# how to launch Spring Batch Job using CommandLineJobRunner having Java configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have my batch job definition in Java based configuration file. I have seen that `CommandLineJobRunner` can be used to launch job, but the job definition should be defined in .xml. I want to use `CommandLineJobRunner` to run my jobs defined in java based configuration.

According to the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html#commandLineJobRunner, there is no details to do so.

Can we even do this? What can be the other alternatives?

Comment: Job doesn't need to be defined in XML. Have you heart about Java config?

Comment: @luboskrnac i know about that. I have defined job in java config only. My question is how to use CommandLineRunner to launch job defined in jAva config.

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you read the docs?

Comment: Yes. I did. In the docs, there is no reference of java based config. We need to give path to .xml having complete reference of application context, name of job and params. Nowhere java based config was mentioned.

Comment: @luboskrnac see here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html#commandLineJobRunner . I dont see any details of using java based configuration.

Comment: @NikhilPareek, did you ever get this to work? I'm seeing the same thing as you: the documentation actually _doesn't_ have a "java-config" way of doing this, it wants XML only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `CommandLineJobRunner` can be either:

- The xml file containing the job definition
- Or the fully qualified name of the configuration class containing the job definition

Starting from Spring Batch v4, there is a toggle on the top of each documentation page that allows you to show examples in Java or Xml config. For example, when the toggle is set to "Java", the documentation section here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromCommandLine shows how to use the `CommandLineJobRunner` with a Java configuration class:

```
$>java -cp your/class/path org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner io.spring.EndOfDayJobConfiguration endOfDay schedule.date(date)=2007/05/05
```

`io.spring.EndOfDayJobConfiguration` is the fully qualified class name containing the `endOfDay` job definition.

Comment: This actually doesn't work. The documentation still asks for an XML file and upon close inspection of the source code, the CommandLineJobRunner still uses the XmlBeanDefinitionReader to try to load the file. Do you know of any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: The `@Configuration` class name if passed will work. Example -  `java -jar batchJar.jar CommandLineJobRunner com.test.configuration.BeanConfguration < jobName> <jobParams>` . Where BeanConfguration is annotated with `@Configuration`

Answer (score 0):

cd to your project, get all dependencies using

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

In your maven project's pom.xml build->plugins secion add follwing

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner</mainClass>
            </configuration>   
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  <mainClass>org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Create project jar using your build method and run from command line.

```
java -cp dependency/* -jar your.jar com.abc.BatchConfigurationA JobA -- parm1=valA,java.lang.String,false parm2=22,java.lang.Long,false
```