# How to Launch Spring batch using CommandLineJobRunner without java configuration instead of XML

Tags: spring-batch

I have a job definition in a java configuration file.  When I try and run the job from gradle task, I get IOException parsing XML Document from class path.  How do I run a job using CommandLineJobRunner without XML configuration?

Gradle

```
task executeJob(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner'
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    args = ["--job_path", "C:\\dev\\git\\ncf-bulk-order\\src\\main\\java\\com\\shelter\\NCFBulkOrder\\Jobs\\NCFBulkOrderConfig.java",
            "--job_id", "Response",
            "--next",
            "--customParam", "value"]
}
```

StackTrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [--job_path]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [--job_path] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:290)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:565)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [--job_path] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to launch Spring Batch Job using CommandLineJobRunner having Java configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250417/how-to-launch-spring-batch-job-using-commandlinejobrunner-having-java-configurat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`CommandLineJobRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.html) expects either the XML file or the Java configuration class containing the Spring application context where your job is defined. Here is an example with a Java config class:

```
java -cp your/class/path \
     org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner \
     com.example.MyJobConfiguration \
     myJob
```

So in your command, you don't need to pass the `--job_path` flag.