# How to launch a Job

Tags: spring, spring-batch, jobs

I'm currently trying to launch a Job programatically in my Spring application.

Here is my actual code:

```
public void launchJob(String[] args)
            throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException,
            JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
        
    String jobName = args[0];

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
    Job job = context.getBean(jobName, Job.class);
    JobParameters jobParameters = getJobParameters(args);


    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    BatchStatus batchStatus = jobExecution.getStatus();
}
```

And how I launch it :

```
String[] args = {"transformXML2CSV", "myFile.xml", "myFile.csv"};
springBatchJobRunner.launchJob(args);
```

But I have some troubles during the launch, the first is to retrieve the app context, my first try was to annotate my class with a `@Service` and use an `@Autowired` like this:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
```

But with this way my `context` is always null.

My second try was to get the context by this way:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringBatchNoDatabaseConfiguration.class);
```

The `SpringBatchNoDatabaseConfiguration` is my `@Configuration` and the Job is inside it.

Using this my `context` is not null but I have a strange behavior and I can't understand why and how to prevent this:

I run the `launchJob` function from my `processor class`, then when I get the `context` by `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` my `processor class` is rebuild and I have a `NullPointerException` in it stopping all the process.

I really don't understand the last part, why it's relaunching my `processor class` when I get the context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in comments above, you run a parent batch (with spring-batch) which at a moment needs your job to process an xml file.

I suggest you keep the same spring-batch context and run the process xml file job as a nested job of the parent job. You can do that using `JobStep` class and spring batch controlling step flow feature. As an example, here is what your parent job would like to :

```java
public Job parentJob(){
   JobParameters processXmlFileJobParameters = getJobParameters(String[]{"transformXML2CSV", "myFile.xml", "myFile.csv"});
   return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("parentJob")
            .start(firstStepOfParentJob())
            .on("PROCESS_XML_FILE").to(processXmlFileStep(processXmlFileJobParameters)
            .from(firstStepOfParentJob()).on("*").to(lastStepOfParentJob())
            .from(processXmlFileStep(processXmlFileJobParameters))
            .next(lastStepOfParentJob())
            .end().build();
}

public Step firstStepOfParentJob(){
   return stepBuilderFactory.get("firstStepOfParentJob")
          // ... depends on your parent job's business
          .build();
}

public Step lastStepOfParentJob(){
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("lastStepOfParentJob")
          // ... depends on your parent job's business
          .build();
} 

public Step processXmlFileStep(JobParameters processXmlFileJobParameters){
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("processXmlFileStep")
                             .job(processXmlFileJob())
                             .parametersExtractor((job,exec)->processXmlFileJobParameters)
                             .build();
}

public Job processXmlFileJob(){
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("processXmlFileJob")
          // ... describe here your xml process job
          .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a second Spring context is initialized with the instruction `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringBatchNoDatabaseConfiguration.class)` so Spring initialiezs your beans a second time.

I recommend you to use Spring boot to [automatically launch your jobs at sartup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-spring-batch-running-jobs-on-startup)

If you don't want to use Spring boot and launch your job manually, your `main` method should look like this :

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] localArgs = {"transformXML2CSV", "myFile.xml", "myFile.csv"};
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringBatchNoDatabaseConfiguration.class);
    Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
    JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
    JobParameters jobParameters = getJobParameters(localArgs);
    jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    // Ohter code to do stuff after the job ends...
}
```

Notice that this code should be completed with your own needs. The class `SpringBatchNoDatabaseConfiguration`has to be anotated with `@Configuration` and `@EnableBatchProcessing`and should define the beans of your job [like this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/configureJob.html#javaConfig)

You can also use the Spring batch class `CommandLineJobRunner` with your java config as explain here : [how to launch Spring Batch Job using CommandLineJobRunner having Java configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250417/how-to-launch-spring-batch-job-using-commandlinejobrunner-having-java-configurat)
It saves writing the code above

Comment: But this will still launch a second Spring Context ? (And I can't use spring boot, it's on a project that is already started since a long time)

Comment: No, my suggestions launch a new java application with a unique spring context for spring batch. Can you please explain which circumstances you are trying to launch the job (from a web app, from an other batch ...) and is there a spring context already loaded ?

Comment: I'm launching it from a Spring Batch, and the context is already loaded. I'm using Camel to process some files, so a XML file cames the batch is launched and in this batch I need to convert my XML to CSV by using this job.

Comment: And when I try to use the context from my batch I have errors like NoSuchBean for Job and JobLauncher

Comment: OK. I didn't understood th context. I'm going to try an other answer.

Comment: Don't worry, I finally found a way using the ApplicationContext from my batch process and send it to the function that launch the job.